# Как сохранять список в многопоточном режиме

Tags: c#, list, tpl, task

Есть список `lst`. В нем список урл. Через `Parallel.For` я делаю гет-запросы и манипулирую с данными. Как мы понимаем данные из списка берутся в случайном порядке и при сбое не представляется возможным нормально продолжить работу. Есть ли какой то метод чтобы `Parallel.For` брал данные по очереди, ну или какой то другой вариант сохранения позиции цикла для всех потоков.

Comment: Берутся-то они по порядку, выполниться могут не по очереди. Что значит `нормально продолжить работу`? Насколько важна очередность? Или достаточно просто запомнить удачно отработанные элементы списка?

Comment: просто запоминать удачно отработанные

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, имеет смысл перейти к task-based-параллеллизму, раз уж у вас всё равно нагрузка на сеть, и не возиться с низкоуроневой многопоточностью.

Если `ProcessUrl` — асинхронная функция обработки *одного* адреса, получаем следующий тривиальный код:

```
var resultTasks = lst.Select(ProcessUrl);
var allResults = await Task.WhenAll(resultTasks);
var successfulResults =
        allResults.Where(r => r != null) // отфильтруем неуспешные
                  .Select(r => r.Value)  // вернёмся к типу byte
                  .ToList();             // и материализуем, наконец.
```

Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx), `Task.WhenAll` возвращает результаты с сохранением порядка:

> `Result` property of the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the results of the supplied tasks in the same order as they were provided

---

Вот пример того, как может выглядеть «обработка одного адреса»:

```
// обработка одного URL, может вернуть null при ошибке
async Task<int?> ProcessUrl(Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri))
        {
            // окей, теперь у нас есть поток
            // интенсивный подсчёт, ограниченный сетью, делаем прямо
            byte sumOfBytes = await SumBytesInStream(stream);
            // вычисление, интенсивное по процессору, выполняем на пуле потоков
            return await Task.Run(() => EncodeByte(sumOfBytes));
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        return null; // неудача, вернём null
    }
}
```

Вспомогательные функции:

```
async Task<byte> SumBytesInStream(Stream s)
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
    byte sum = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var actuallyRead = await s.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            return sum;
        sum += buf.Take(actuallyRead).Sum();
    }
}

byte EncodeByte(byte b)
{
    // тут много сложной криптографии
    return b + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и через одну коллекцию:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<Uri, Enum> cd = new ConcurrentDictionary<Uri, Enum>();

        cd.TryAdd(new Uri("http://1.com"), EProgress.Waiting);
        cd.TryAdd(new Uri("http://2.com"), EProgress.Waiting);
        cd.TryAdd(new Uri("http://3.com"), EProgress.Waiting);


        Parallel.ForEach(cd, item =>
        {
            try
            {
                cd[item.Key] = EProgress.Processing;
                // to do something
                cd[item.Key] = EProgress.Complete;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cd[item.Key] = EProgress.Error;
                throw;
            }
        });
    }

    public enum EProgress
    {
        Waiting, // Ожидают обработки
        Processing, // В процессе обработки
        Complete // Удачно завершенные
    }
```

После выполнения можно посмотреть на каком элементе ошибка, и в каком состоянии остальные.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше конечно тасками оперировать и проще получиться и быстрее.
Хранить, на мой сугубо условный взгляд, стоит 2 коллекции.
Как только отработает запрос корректно, адрес добавляется в коллекцию проверенных.
Соответственно для работы используем конкурентные коллекции, к примеру, *ConcurrentQueue*